# String's empty character is not trimed in sql

Tags: sql, substring, trim

The empty string character cannot be removed from a record when I do `SUBSTRING(LTRIM())`

I have the following record in the table `' T1234567890'` after I copied it to a query analyzer from a table's cell.

When I do select `SUBSTRING(LTRIM(' T12345678909'),1,1)`, I'm getting 'T'.

However, when I do select `SUBSTRING(LTRIM(Data),1,1) from MyTable`, I'm getting an empty space.

Any ideas why it happens and what is a possible fix?

Comment: What looks like a space probably isn't a space.

Comment: Perhaps [Non-breaking space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space)

Comment: I understand that it is not a space. But how I remove it? I tried `replace(ltrim(Data), char(20),''`). But it did not work

Comment: Try `UNICODE(Data)` to find out what the initial character is.

Comment: Thx. Yeah. `Unicode(Data)` showed `10` on the first position

Answer (score 1):

check some of the your data having no values with space only. in that case you get only space.

try to use the below query

```
 select case when ltrim(data) like '[a-z]%' then
 substring(data,patindex('%[a-z]%',data),1)
 when ltrim(data) like '[0-9]%' then
 substring(data,patindex('%[0-9]%', data),1)
 end 
 from table
 where data like '%[a-z]%' or data like '%[0-9]%'
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is obvious, that there will be always that unwanted character in the string, you can make your selection directly as below-

```
 select SUBSTRING(Data,2,1) from MyTable
```